# Update object with the same value

Tags: javascript

I use the following code which is working OK, now I want to add some value to it the Dest and its not working,

**This is working**

```
var str = '\
BASH=/bin/sh\n
CF_INSTANCE_P=\'[{external:500,internal:501}]\'\n\
COLUMNS=80'

var obj = {};
str.split('\n').forEach(function (el) {
  var spl = el.split('=');
  obj[spl[0]] = spl[1];
});

console.log(obj)
```

Now I need to add the following to the str (under COLUMNS=80) ,and its not working (I see just the dest entry and not all the other,I know its becouse of the '=' which is not there but how to work with all this secnarios )? I need to add it to **obj like all other value**

```
dest='[
    {"name":"satr", "url":"https://sd.com", "proxyHost":"pu.corp", "proxyPort":"8080"}
]'
```

UPDATE

The str here is just for demo Im getting it form readFile **as-is** and I cannot change it...

Comment: Can you write what you expect as output? Because it's not quite clear in the post...

Comment: You split the string by newlines. In `dest='[...]'` there are three extra newlines in your example code. Try leaving the right hand side of `dest=` on one line.

Comment: @CViejo -  I need to see 3 new enties in obj for every line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
var str = '\
BASH=/bin/sh\n\
BASH_ARGC=()\n\
BASH_ARGV=()\n\
BASH_LINENO=([0]="0")\n\
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="2" [2]="51" [3]="1" [4]="release" )\n\
BASH_VERSION=\'3.2.2(1)-release\'\n\
CF_INSTANCE_P=\'[{external:500,internal:501}]\'\n\
COLUMNS=80\'\n\
DEST=\'[{"name":"satr", "url":"https://sd.com", "proxyHost":"pu.corp", "proxyPort":"8080"}]'


var obj = {};
str.split('\n').forEach(function (el) {
  var spl = el.split('=');
  obj[spl[0]] = spl[1];
});

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks but I need in object to be 3 new entries one for dest one for the "json" and one for the enclosing ,Btw Im getting this str from read file so I cannot change it :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just add it like this after parsing the string:

```
obj.dest = [{"name":"satr", "url":"https://sd.com", "proxyHost":"pu.corp", "proxyPort":"8080"}];
```

Comment: Ok, could you update your post with how you want `obj` to be like after parsing the whole string?